# Removing an empty div with class attribute and contenteditable value set

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using the jQuery code to remove empty divs from my HTML upon click, so that the HTML data can be saved:

```
$("div:empty").remove();
```

This is failing to remove the following divs:

```
<div class="row" contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

I thought that this would qualify as empty. Any ideas on how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, The following snippet will return the div elements with unnecessary empty spaces also.

```
$("div").filter(function(){   
    return $(this).text().trim() == ""
}).remove();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3Rb4T/)

Comment: I don't understand why exactly you need trim, you clearly do but why doesn't text equals `""`?

Comment: I thought this was working but its removing this div which i didnt expect: <div id="image1T1Div" class="article_media"> <img id="image1T1" src="/images/email-placeholder.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""> </div>

Comment: @Jay try this out http://jsfiddle.net/3Rb4T/2/  If this works for you, just comment me back, I'll update it in my original answer.

Answer (score 4):

That div contains empty space, which is considered "text" by jQuery and as such won't be selected as empty.

This markup does match the empty selector:

```
<div class="row" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: can i remove the empty space?

Comment: Look at @Rajaprabhu's answer :-)